# PubNub response time too long

Tags: angularjs, pubnub

I've implemented a basic chat app with PubNub in Angular and noticed that the response time after a publish is really long.

Testing the process on the [tutorial sample](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/build-real-time-chat-10-lines-code/) does the same thing -
TTFB is 2.2 minutes.

Request URL: http://ps5.pubnub.com/subscribe/demo/chat/0/14358752049456252?uuid=6cf0c87b-6379-430c-98d4-8c9be14b1db9

Response: [[],"14358752049456252"]

Anyone have an idea why this trip is taking so long?

Comment: Hi There good question.  You are likely seeing the long-poll keep-alive socket return data in that time span.  This is normal and in fact a very good thing which provides network efficiencies and timeliness of delivery of realtime data to your browser and devices.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying; you may post as answer.

Comment: Thank you just posted as answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PubNub Response Time Too Long

You are likely seeing the long-poll keep-alive socket return data in that time span from within Chrome's Developer Console Network Tab. This is normal. In fact it is a very good thing which provides network efficiencies and timeliness of delivery of realtime data to your browser and devices.